# C# Dynamic size indexers

Tags: c#

How to set up indexer that are dynamically grown in size ?Down,i used the fixed size array.
If i use `List<Employee>` ,then there is no point to have indexers.so how can i keep the 
array to grow dynamically?

```
class Department
{
    private Employee[] employee = new Employee[6];

    public Employee this[int arg]
    {
        get { return this.employee[arg]; }
        set { this.employee[arg] = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to create a new array if the index is bigger than the current size, and copy the existing contents into the new array. [`Array.Resize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) will do this for you. (Note that it doesn't change the existing array - it returns you a new array of the specified size, containing the previous elements.)

You may want to consider resizing to a larger array than you really need, just so that you don't have to resize as often.

Are you sure it wouldn't be easier just to use a `List<T>` though? Doing this sort of thing manually is rather tedious when it's built into the framework already...

Comment: Thanks Jon then I will go for List<T>

Comment: can you please post how you resolved this issue? I am stuck with the same problem too

Answer (score 2):

> If i use List ,then there is
>   no point to have indexers

Why? You can still using indexes with lists, and you can define the initial capacity of the list at construction time. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0cyc8ex.aspx